# Assets pipeline images subdirectories heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sass, assets

Ok so I have a subdirectory called *icons* in *assets/images/icons*.

In my css, which use sass, if I do:

`background: transparent image-url("mobile.png") no-repeat left center;`

And then push to heroku, it works flawlessly, the background displays no problem.

But if I do:

`background: transparent image-url("icons/mobile.png") no-repeat left center;`

The background simply does not show up.

What I found so far:

- All the background url in my css for images showing up (the ones not in a subdirectory) are `/assets/mobile-circle-header-fac4f74ae28c8147aaf9dbca8fb110e8.png`
- Images in a subdirectory that are not showing up are like `/assets/icons/mobile.png` with no digest.
- I have images in subdirectories that shows up in my html when I call them via image_tag, so the problem must be isolated to sass.

If you need any more informations, just ask away.

thanks!

**EDIT**

When I rename the subdirectory to something else than "icons", it works :O, any ideas? lol...

Comment: Is `image-url("icons/mobile.png")` working locally?  Are you making sure to recompile your assets before pushing that change?

Comment: Yes it works locally. assets are compiled on the side of heroku at each push!

Comment: When I test in production on my Pow.cx local env. the images in the icons subdirectory has the digest and shows up

Comment: Oh wow, it worked by renaming the folder icons to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Ha - just had the same error and it was because `Icon?` was in ~/.gitignore_global.  I must have added that way back, an OS generated file was the comment.

Note - you can look in the asset precompile directory on heroku

```
$ heroku run bash
$ ls public/assets
```

to see if your assets were compiled at all.  By default, all image subdirectories should be added.  This may help figure out if there are other issues.